# how to create fields dynamically like product custom options using custom module in admin panel in magento

Tags: magento

I want to create dynamic fields using custom module in admin panel in magento.

It must be like custom options which is under product section.

Somebody give me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you search for something like [this](http://mustakarhu.com/blog/dynamic-input-field-in-magento-admin-configuration/)?